# EventEmitter.removeListener('change', ...)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting warning

```
EventEmitter.removeListener('change', ...): Method has been deprecated. Please instead use `remove()` on the subscription returned by `EventEmitter.addListener`
```

on that function

```
const addData = (todo_name)=>{
 firestore()
    .collection(constants.collection_name)
    .add({
      is_completed: false,
      is_deleted: false,
      todo: todo_name,
    })
    .then(res => showSuccess(constants.todoAdded))
    .catch(error => {
      showError(error);
    });
}
const onAddTodo = async () => {
    updateState({isLoading: true});
    await addData(todoName); // add todo in data base and after that update the list
    getTodos();
  };
```

can anyone tell me why I'm getting that warning?

Comment: The warning is not supposed to get triggered by the code you mentioned above. TO confirm this Try commenting the code and run the project again if you see the same warning again then this code has nothing to do with the warning.

Comment: I'm wondering same thing, I comment that code addData() and I didn't get warning

Comment: Then the issue must be related to firestore. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I'm getting that warning from `react-native-flash-message` I added ans too

Comment: I'm getting this switching between DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator depending on login status.